# Password failing using Bcrypt

Tags: bcrypt, password-storage

So far bcrypt has had no problems until now. For some reason the following password won't work. `UIO78349%^&(]\\';=` This is the first time I've had a password not work and I hope somebody has an explanation. I hunted the net and read about the character limit but this is well below that. Not sure if it makes any difference but the user input for password is going through mysqli_real_escape_string.

First batch of code where the login form is located:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="sidebar-signin-block.php">

        <table width="90%" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="white">


            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="ffffff" colspan="2" align="center"><h2>User Login</h2></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td align="right">Email:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td align="right">Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="login" value="Login"></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><h3 style="margin-top:7px;"><a href="nonadmin_user_forgot_password.php" target="_blank" title="Reset Your Lost Password">Forgot Password?</a></h3></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ffffff" colspan="2" align="center"><div style="padding-top:5px;"><span style="font-size:20px;">Don't have an account?<br /><a href="/includes/register-user.php" title="Register with us!" target="_self">Sign Up</a> is <em>quick</em> and <em>easy</em>!</span></div></td>

        </table>
    </form>

    <?php 

// Connecting to the database and making the Bcrypt functions available
include("admin/includes/connect.php");
include ("lib/password.php");

// Gathering and sanitizing user login input
if(isset($_POST['login'])){

    $email = trim(((isset($conn) && is_object($conn)) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']) :((trigger_error  ("[MySQLConverterToo] Fix the mysql_escape_string() call! This code does not work.", E_USER_ERROR)) ? "" : "")));

        $pass = trim(((isset($conn) && is_object($conn)) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']) : ((trigger_error   ("[MySQLConverterToo] Fix the mysql_escape_string() call! This code does not work.", E_USER_ERROR)) ? "" : "")));

         // Checking the database records for the user login input
        $hash_query = "select nonadmin_user_pass from nonadmin_user_login where email='$email'";{
                $run_query = mysqli_query($conn, $hash_query);}
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_query)) {
                $fetch_pass = $row['nonadmin_user_pass'];
                    }
        // If the user email and password matches we start a session                               
        if ((password_verify($pass, $fetch_pass)) == 1){

              // Verifying user login success with splash page then sending user back to the home page
              $_SESSION['email']=$email;
              echo "<script>window.open('login-success.php','_self')</script>";}

    // When the user login fails an alert is given to inform them
    else {
    echo "<script>alert('Email or password is incorrect please try again')</script>";
    echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";}  
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Here the js.

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){
$("#login").click(function(){
var email = $("#email").val();
var password = $("#password").val();
// Checking for blank fields.
if( email =='' || password ==''){
$('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]');
$('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]');
alert("Please fill all fields.");
}else {
$.post("log-me-in.php",{ email1: email, password1:password},
function(data) {
if(data=='Invalid Email.......') {
$('input[type="text"]');
$('input[type="password"]');
alert(data);
}else if(data=='Email or Password is wrong please try again.'){
$('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]');
alert(data);
} else if(data=='Successfully Logged in.'){
window.location.reload();
$("form")[0].reset();
$('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]');
alert(data);
} else{
alert(data);
}
});
}
});
});</script>
```

Here's the php being called:

```
<?php 
session_start();
// Connecting to the database and making the Bcrypt functions available
include("admin/includes/connect.php");
include ("lib/password.php");

$email=$_POST['email1']; // Fetching Values from URL.
$password= ($_POST['password1']); 
// check if e-mail address syntax is valid or not
//$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); // sanitizing email(Remove unexpected symbol like <,>,?,#,!, etc.)
//if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
//echo "Invalid Email.......";
//}else{
// Matching user input email and password with stored email and password in database.
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM nonadmin_user_login WHERE email='$email'");
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$bcrypt_pass = $data['nonadmin_user_pass'];
$email_match = $data['email'];

if (password_verify ($password, $bcrypt_pass) == 1 AND $email == $email_match) {

$_SESSION['email']=$email;
echo "Successfully Logged in.";
}

else{
echo "Email or Password is wrong please try again";
}

//}
?>

Here is the user registration code where the password initially gets entered before mail verification:

    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Register at Recycling Kansas City</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/register-user.css" media="all">

    <!-- ie compatibility -->
    <!--[if IE]>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="Site/javascript/bootstrap/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <meta content="recycling kansas city, recycling centers, recycling locations" name="keywords">
    <meta content="Recycling Kansas City is an efficient resource to help you quickly find a recycle center that is nearby. Use our map to find locations and accepted items." name="description">
         </head>



    <h1 class="center">Why register at Recycling Kansas City?</h1>

    <p>By registering here you will gain access to additional features. Once registered you can create your own custom profile, submit and comment on blog articles, advertise your products or services and have the choice to opt in for email announcements.</p>

    <p>All of your information will be securely stored in our database and you can delete your account at any time. Also, rest assured that we will never share any of your submitted details with anyone ever.</p>

    <form method="post" action="register-user.php">

            <table width="520" border="10" align="center" bgcolor="white">


                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="ffffff" colspan="2" align="center"><h1>Registration</h1></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td align="right">Email</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="email" size="53"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td align="right">Password:</td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="pwd" size="53"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">User Name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="name" size="53"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="register" value="Register"></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </form>
    </html>



    <?php

    include ("../admin/includes/connect.php");
    include ("../lib/password.php");

    $con = new mysqli("localhost", "$username", "$password", "$database");

    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    if(isset($_POST['register'])){

    $email = trim(mysql_escape_string($_POST['email']));

    $nonadmin_user_pass = trim(mysql_escape_string($_POST['pwd']));

    $password = password_hash($nonadmin_user_pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

    $nonadmin_user_name = trim(mysql_escape_string($_POST['name']));

    $query_verify_email = "SELECT * FROM nonadmin_user_login WHERE email ='$email' and verified = 1";

    $verified_email = mysqli_query($con,$query_verify_email);

    if (!$verified_email) {

    echo ' System Error';
    }

    if (mysqli_num_rows($verified_email) == 0) {

    // Generate a unique code:

    $hash = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));

    $query_create_user = "INSERT INTO `nonadmin_user_login` (`email`, `nonadmin_user_pass`, `nonadmin_user_name`,  `hash`) VALUES ('$email', '$password', '$nonadmin_user_name', '$hash')";

    $created_user = mysqli_query($con,$query_create_user);

    if (!$created_user) {

    echo 'Query Failed ';
    }

    if (mysqli_affected_rows($con) == 1) { //If the Insert Query was successfull.

    $subject = 'Activate Your Email';

    $headers = "From: admin@recyclingkansascity.com \r\n";

    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    $url= 'http://recyclingkansascity.com/includes/register-verify.php?email=' . urlencode($email) . "&key=$hash";

    $message ='<p>To activate your account please click on Activate buttton</p>';

    $message.='<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> <tr>';

    $message .= '<td align="center" width="300" height="40" bgcolor="#000091" style="-webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px;

    color: #ffffff; display: block;">';

    $message .= '<a href="'.$url.'" style="color: #ffffff; font-size:16px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none;

    line-height:40px; width:100%; display:inline-block">Click to Activate</a>';

    $message .= '</td> </tr> </table>';

    mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);

    echo '<p class="center">A confirmation email

    has been sent to <b>'. $email.' </b></p><p class="center">Please <strong>click</strong> on the <strong><em>Activate</em> Button</strong> to Activate your account.</p> ';

    } else { // If it did not run OK.

    echo '<div>You could not be registered due to a system

    error. We apologize for any

    inconvenience.</div>';

    }

    }

    else{

    echo '<div>Email already registered</div>';}

    }
    ?>
```

So far never a hiccup on any password until the password at the top of the post? Weird if you ask me.

Comment: We're going to need to see some code to debug this problem, I reckon.

Comment: Remove all calls to `mysqli_real_escape_string()` for password input, the functions `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` accept even binary input and are not prone to SQL-injection. I assume this already solves your problem. Then the function `password_verify()` already returns a boolean, no need to compare it with `== 1`. If this doesn't solve your problem, i would make sure that every page uses UTF-8 as file format and defined it in the header.

Comment: martinstoeckli thank you so much for the input! I made the changes you suggested and now it works like a dream. Your expert input is greatly appreciated! I just tried to mark the question as answered but couldn't find the needed input? Any suggestions how to mark this question as answered?

Comment: @DisasterFaster - Glad id worked. You cannot mark it as answered, because it is only a comment. I added it as an answer now.

Comment: Thank you martinstoeckli and I upvoted it and marked it answered. Thanks a bunch for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all calls to `mysqli_real_escape_string()` for password input, the functions [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) accept even binary input and are not prone to SQL-injection. I assume this already solves your problem. Escaping should be done as late as possible and only for the given target system, so the function mysqli_real_escape_string() should only be called to build an SQL query.

Then the function password_verify() already returns a boolean, no need to compare it with == 1.

```
if (password_verify($pass, $fetch_pass))
{
  ...
}
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, i would make sure that every page uses UTF-8 as file format and defined it in the header.